# How can I determine if Office 2010 SP2 is installed, via batch?

Tags: batch-file, microsoft-office-2010

I'm whipping up a little script that does some reporting on which of my computers has Service Pack 2 for Office 2010 installed. I'm using batch because some are Windows XP without Powershell available, while the rest is Windows 7.

How can I determine if it's already installed via batch? Registry key, file versions or similar methods are all fine, I just need it to be reliable. So far the only methods I've seen are all desktop-based and I need to run this as a scheduled task.

And I'm not necessarily looking for someone to write any script for me, just a method by which batch could potentially grab this info.

Comment: [Need to remotely determine what version of Microsoft Office is installed](//serverfault.com/q/109287)

Comment: This is certainly not too broad of a question, as there's likely only a couple methods by which this could be accomplished.

Comment: We are not a script writing service.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't ask anyone to write a script. I'm looking for a registry entry, file version or other method by which batch can access. You don't need to reference a single line of script in your answer if you prefer.

Comment: Did you read the answer David mentioned? It does contain the rough registry location you need to work from. At least if it's a normal install it should be in that location. You either check whenever that registry key is set accordingly or test whenever the Office 2010 installation directory exists (assuming no manual changes to installation path). [Check folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033801/checking-if-a-folder-exists-using-a-bat-file), [check registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458001/check-if-registry-key-value-exists-and-if-so-log-it).

Comment: [quick command or batch script to determine Windows and Office version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820434/quick-command-or-batch-script-to-determine-windows-and-office-version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out PSInfo, which is part of the [Sysinternals Suite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite).  You can run the command

> psinfo /s \\remotecomputername

to get a list of software installed on that computer.

Comment: Combining that with `findstr` worked perfectly. And it even works on NT systems. Cool, and thanks!